# Почему я получаю Undefined variable?

Tags: php

Есть такой код класса

```
class genMailData {
    public $mailData = [];


    public function set_xrand() {
        $this->mailData['test'] = rand(1234, 99999999);
    }

    public function result() {
        return $this->$mailData;
    }

}
```

Вызываю так:

```
$GMD = new genMailData();
$GMD->set_xrand();

var_export( $GMD->result() );
```

В ответ получаю

> Notice: Undefined variable: mailData in test.php on line 15

> Notice: Undefined property: genMailData::$ in test.php on line 15

> NULL

Ругается на эту строку:

```
public function result() {
    return $this->$mailData; //на эту строку ругается
}
```

php 7.3

Comment: Потому что не нужно ставить $ после ->, доступ к члену осуществляется через $this->mailData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что не

```
$this->$mailData;
```

а

```
$this->mailData;
```

Советую поучить основы ООП получше

Comment: о божечки. точно! спасибо огромное.

Comment: Если всё ок - галочку слева от ответа тык